# Please explain this URL structure

Tags: url, homepage

When I navigate to www.aap.org the url in my browser is converted to:

http://www.aap.org/en-us/Pages/Default.aspx?nfstatus=401&nftoken=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&nfstatusdescription=ERROR%3a+No+local+token

I am not on the IT side of things, but would like the community's take on whether this is normal behavior for a website or if our web vendor is doing something untoward. It just strikes me as a strange way to handle whether a user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some sort of JavaScript blocked.
When I access the Site with Firefox and NoScript active i get the same link, when I turn it of (thus allowing Javascript) I get:

http://www.aap.org/en-us/Pages/Default.aspx

I can't give you exact info what all that above stuff in your url means, but it seems like some empty user identifier or cookie.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Is it normal to append the /Default.aspx information? My intuition is that this information should just be hidden from the user but I am obviously a novice with regards to this aspect of programming.

Comment: This is different from site to site i guess, but i never worked with ASP, maybe the article on wikipedia will provide you with more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET it is in fact pretty common, that you can see the file you are requesting from the server. like index.php (for php obviously) but you will not get the code, the server just sends you the html it generates by using certain information together with the code. in you above example the &nftoken=000... etc is such information that is processed by the server.